# Biblatex: How can I include all the authors for a single \citeauthor{} command?

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to cite authors inline:

```tex
\citeauthor{label} have shown...
```

While normally I would just use "Author A *et al.*", in this single instance I would like to expand all authors. This is because the authors of this paper are often grouped under an abbreviation (the ABCD theorem (from Authors A, B, C and D) states...).

How can I expand all the authors for just this one paper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a one-off you can use `\AtNextCite{\AtEachCitekey{\defcounter{maxnames}{999}}}` before the `\citeauthor` you want to mention all names.

Of course this quickly becomes tedious, so it is strongly recommended to package this up into a new command (`\citeallauthors`, say).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\newrobustcmd*{\citeallauthors}{%
  \AtNextCite{\AtEachCitekey{\defcounter{maxnames}{999}}}%
  \citeauthor}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk and Annie Hacker and James Hacker and Humphrey Appleby},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \citeauthor{elk}
ipsum \AtNextCite{\AtEachCitekey{\defcounter{maxnames}{999}}}\citeauthor{elk}
ipsum \citeallauthors{elk}

Lorem \citeauthor{yoon}
ipsum \citeauthor{companion}
dolor \citeauthor{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem Elk et al. ipsum Elk, Hacker, Hacker and Appleby ipsum Elk, Hacker, Hacker and Appleby]

This solution requires you to select manually that you want to mention all names. If you always want to mention all names of a particular source, use the `maxcitenames` option on a per-entry level.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk and Annie Hacker and James Hacker and Humphrey Appleby},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
  options   = {maxcitenames=999},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \citeauthor{elk}

Lorem \citeauthor{yoon}
ipsum \citeauthor{companion}
dolor \citeauthor{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem Elk, Hacker, Hacker and Appleby]